# Cannot convert IQueryable<Grouping> to IQueryable<Model>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm stuck on this problem. I am trying to return an IQueryable list of my model(Group). Which I will then return to a view and display in a drop down box. I had it working. However, when I added a GroupBy, I received the following error:

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int,Entities.Group>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Entities.Group>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Controller:

```
model.ClaimGroups = supplierGroupRepo.GetAllSupplierClaimGroupsByClient(model.ClientID)
                                     .OrderBy( r=> r.GroupName)
                                     .GroupBy( r=> r.GroupID);
```

LINQ:

```
public class SQLSupplierGroupRepository : ISupplierGroupRepository {
        ApplicationDbContext Db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Group> GetAllSupplierClaimGroupsByClient(int ClientID) {
            return (from sg in Db.Group
                     where sg.ClientID == ClientID
                     select sg);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if (camOnlineDb != null) {
                camOnlineDb.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that I can order by in either the controller or in the LINQ statement. However, I tried this and the OrderBy didn't seem to make a difference to the results.

EDIT:

I tried this in LINQ and this didn't seem to make a difference to the ordering of the results:

```
public IQueryable<Group> GetAllSupplierClaimGroupsByClient(int ClientID) {
            var x =  (from sg in Db.Group
                     where sg.ClientID == ClientID
                     select sg);

            x.OrderBy(r => r.GroupName);
            x.GroupBy(r => r.GroupID);
            x.Select(g => new Group {
                GroupID = g.GroupID,
                GroupName = g.GroupName
            });


            return x;
        }
```

Comment: You need to project your output using `Select` to return `IQueryable<Entities.Group>`. Currently it is returning `IQueryable<IGrouping<int,Entities.Group<TKey,T>`

Comment: I've literally just tried this and it didn't work. Ill add an edit to show you

Comment: As per you edit, first of all you can't do this: `GroupID = g.GroupID` instead you need to do `GroupID = g.Key`. Secondly for fetching `GroupName` you need to specify which GroupName you need from each group as `g` will contain a list of `GroupName` under each GroupID. Apart from this why you are mixing query and method syntax? You can do all this by chaining different methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had to ask a colleague for help with this one, my problem was two fold. But I only asked one question. The result is as follows:

```
 public IEnumerable<GroupModel> GetAllSupplierClaimGroupsByClientGrouping(int ClientID) {

            var x = (from g in camOnlineDb.Group
                     where g.ClientID == 1
                     group g by new { GroupID = g.GroupID, GroupName = g.GroupName }
                         into a
                         select new GroupModel{ GroupID = a.Key.GroupID, GroupName = a.Key.GroupName });
            return x.OrderBy( r=> r.GroupName);
        }
```

Comment: If you see my last comment this is exactly what I suggested you :) To project you model based on grouping key.

Comment: I noticed. Thank you for your help!